# Does Lombok @Data override the existing toString and hashCode methods?

Tags: java, lombok

Recently we started make use of Lombok features in our project. we have `@Data` annotation for the Domain object, due to this running with some exception thrown by `hashCode()` method provided by Lombok api. Later, when I added `@Setter` and `@Getter` instead of `@Data`, I didn't see any issues.

**Question1:** Does Lombok `@Data` override the existing methods in a class like `hashCode()` and `toString()`?

**Question2:** why is `hashCode()` making problems here?

Answer (score 25):

Yes, `@Data` implies `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@ToString`. See [the `@Data` documentation](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html).

The generated `hashCode()` method will call the hashCode methods for all fields. So if one of the values of the fields throws an exception, so will this.

One other scenario is that you have circular object references: If one object has a field that contains an object that has a field that refers to the first object, invoking the hashCode method will trigger a StackOverflow.

Disclosure: I am one of the Lombok developers.

Comment: how can I exclude circular object references from @data? can I annotate a field to be ignored?

Comment: You can add @EqualsAndHashCode(exclude="foo")

Comment: Using the generated toString method  will also trigger a stackOverflowError. You should also add: `@ToString(exclude="foo")`